# How to write Shell Script for Mongo Find query.?

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

I am new to shell scripting. Actually I am writing a shell script for `mongo` to find specific document, this shell script accepts an argument and uses in `find`. I had written a simple find query:

```
mongo poc --eval "printjson(db.users.find().toArray())"
```

That's working fine, but now problem is that when I want to find specific document by passing users id that gives null records, so here is my shell script:

```
mongo poc --eval "printjson(db.users.find({"userid":"$1"}).toArray())"
```

I don't know what is wrong, please help so that i would be able to write for **update** and **remove** query as well.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you are trying to use double quotes inside a quoted string in your Bash script.

You should either:

- Use single quotes:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  mongo poc --eval "printjson(db.users.find({'userid':'$1'}).toArray())"
  ```
- Escape the double quotes inside the string:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  mongo poc --eval "printjson(db.users.find({\"userid\":\"$1\"}).toArray())"
  ```

For more details, see: [Bash quotes and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).